# How to set the format of a spreadsheet cell to "date" using SpreadSheetApp and google App script

Tags: google-apps-script

I need to set the format of a cell to "date" in a google spreadsheet with google app script (preferably with the spreadsheet app), so that when a persons clicks the cell a calendar pops up.

Answer (score 3):

This can be achieved with the `.setNumberFormat()` method.

---

#### Example

See function below (adapted from [Google's documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setNumberFormat(String))):

```js
function setFormat() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];

  var cell = sheet.getRange("B2");
  // Set to date format
  cell.setNumberFormat("yyyy-mm-dd");
}
```

**Note:** If you're trying to achieve this for a larger range (more than 1 cell), you'll need to use `.setNumberFormats()` instead, [here's the documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setNumberFormats(Object)) for that method.

---

#### References

- [`.setNumberFormat()` Documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setNumberFormat(String))
- [`.setNumberFormats()` Documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setNumberFormats(Object))
- [Date and Number Formats](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/formats)

Answer (score 0):

If you want the calendar to show when you click a cell, do it like this:

```
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
var range = sheet.getRange("A1:A10"); 
range.setNumberFormat("dd/MM/yyyy"); 
range.setDataValidation(SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireDate().setAllowInvalid(false).build());
```